# WooCommerce Rest API - Get Orders using after and before parameters in UTC format, returns orders in local timezone

Tags: rest, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm calling the GET statement for WooCommerce Order API, and to limit the result set I'm always using before and after parameters.

However, even if the given dates are ISO8601 compliant and with Z to signal it's UTC, API is still returning as if the date parameters are in local timezone:

API GET Statement URL:

```
[siteurl]/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?after=2021-01-12 12:15:15Z&before=2021-01-12 12:15:17Z
```

[Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsblc.png)

The order I got as a result has this for date_created:

```html
"date_created": "2021-01-12T12:15:16",
"date_created_gmt": "2021-01-12T17:15:16",
```

I should not get this order since date_created_gmt is outside of the given parameters.